# Is there way to determine height of rectangle in centimetres, provided I know left, right, top, bottom co-ordinates?

Tags: opencv, python-3.6, measure

I'm using opencv, I have left, right, top, bottom co-ordinates of a rectangle. 
I want to measure width and height of the rectangle in centimeters. How do I do that?

I tried to find euclidean distance like this:
`D = dist.euclidean((top, left), (top, right))`, but am not sure whether it is right or not, because I want a value of height and width in centimeters

Code segment that I use to determine the co-ordinates

```
(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) = (box[num][1], box[num][0], box[num][3], box[num][2])

(left, right, top, bottom) = (xmin * im_width, xmax * im_width, ymin * im_height, ymax * im_height)
```

Comment: Width is the difference between right and left, height the difference between top and bottom, if it’s a bounding box or other axis aligned one. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, yes sami exactly but can I get that value in a specific metric like metres/centimetres/inches

Comment: If you know the physical size of the image and possible geometric distortions within, sure.

Comment: You can "calibrate" your software with a reference shape with known dimensions (ruler) and than let your software compare the coordinates of your rectangle with the reference shape after that it is a simple rule of proportion calculation. Most optical measuring systems in industrial applications work that way. This method does require/presume that your object is parallel to your optics (and centered on the axes) otherwise geometric distortions and other effects will decrease the accuracy of measurement.